# ifelse statement based on vector of conditions in r

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

Let's say I have a simple data-frame with a list of IDs like this:

```
df<-tibble(id=1:5)
```

Then I have a vector of IDs like this:

```
ids<-3:7
```

I am trying to write an `if` or `ifelse` statement that will check to see if each `id` is contained in any ids in the `ids` vector. The result would be something like:

```
df1<-tibble(id=1:5,included=c("no","no","yes","yes","yes"))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
     id included
  <int> <chr>   
    1     no      
    2     no      
    3     yes     
    4     yes     
    5     yes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ifelse functions works on vectors. You were probably looking for the %in% operator? Did you try google?

```
df$included <- ifelse(df$id %in% ids, "yes", "no")
```

Comment: Yep, I Googled in and tried a few different solutions with with %in% operator and couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `%in%` to create a logical vector and replace the values based on either `ifelse` or `case_when` or just by indexing

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
    mutate(included = case_when(id  %in% ids ~  "yes", TRUE ~ "no"))
df
```

Comment: LOL your super powers are slipping today @akrun, you meant `df %>% mutate(included = case_when(id  %in% ids ~ "yes", TRUE ~ "no"))`

Comment: @ChuckP sorry, there is a typo as I didn't check test it

Answer (score 3):

`R base`:

```
df$included <- df$id %in% ids
df
# A tibble: 5 x 2
     id included
  <int> <lgl>   
1     1 FALSE   
2     2 FALSE   
3     3 TRUE    
4     4 TRUE    
5     5 TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%in%` to subset a vector containing *no* and *yes*:

```
df$included <- c("no", "yes")[1 + df$id %in% ids]
## A tibble: 5 x 2
#     id included
#  <int> <chr>   
#1     1 no      
#2     2 no      
#3     3 yes     
#4     4 yes     
#5     5 yes
```